# Я хочу чтоб className мог меняться в зависимости от полученных props

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Я хочу чтоб className мог меняться в зависимости от полученных props.
Ну ещё я использую module.css и пусть мой модуль называется - s
И как в таком отрывке кода сделать так чтоб className был значением переменной loh (не считая того что прибавляет module.css), а не просто - loh(не считая того что прибавляет module.css).

let loh = 'привет';
className = {s.loh}  --- там это всё в компоненте естественно, но я уже не писал.

Буду очень благодарен)

Comment: используйте `classnames`

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете написать условие в jsx

```
<p className={props.loh === 'привет' ? 'test' : 'test2'}>test</p>
```